# Admin Page Access

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a page which only admins can access once they click a link. If the logged in user is a standard user then they should not be able to access the page. However, when a standard user tries to access the admin page they have access to the page.

I would appreciate a pair of second eyes to see if they can spot anything wrong with the code which would make the functionality work as intended.

Thanks

```
<?php

if(check_login() && isAdmin()) {
   echo 'welcome administrator';
} else {
   header('Location: login.php');
   exit;
}

function isAdmin() {
   $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "dbpass", "dbname") or die ('Could not connect to database!');  
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM `usertable` WHERE userID ='" . $_SESSION['sess_uid'] . "'";
   $mainaccess = $conn->query($sql);
   print_r($mainaccess);
if(!$mainaccess){
    echo $conn->error;
}


if ($mainaccess -> userLevel == 0) {
    return true;
} else {
     return false;
}
}

function check_login () {
if(isset($_SESSION['sess_uid']) && $_SESSION['sess_uid'] != '') {
   return true;
} else {
   false;
   return;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Is that the real SQL? Because you don't seem to be filtering on a username or ID? Hence it will always return the admin account

Comment: I thought that was all I was looking for though, as I only want admin accounts to access the page. Thats the real SQL.

Comment: Agreed with Trent, how are you checking that particular user. You do not check by the users id, which is what needs to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are selecting from the database users where they have admin access already ie

```
SELECT `userID` FROM `usertable` WHERE `userLevel` = 0
```

So you are always showing anyone as an admin. The query needs to be changed to check specifically if the logged in user is an admin. So changing the query to something like so

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `usertable` WHERE userID = $_SESSION['sess_uid']";
```

Where `$_SESSION['sess_uid']` is the `userID`

We have to remove both the `userLevel` check, as this is irrelevant when selecting the user, we also have to change from `SELECT userID`, to `SELECT *`, as if you only select the `userID`, you will not have the `userLevel` in your array and the line

```
$mainaccess -> 'userLevel' == 0
```

Will not work. By selecting everything you ensure all attributes can be accessed, ie

```
$mainaccess -> 'userLevel'
$mainaccess -> 'userID'
```

**Update**

The correct way to access the table data will be using either

Object (this is the method you will use)

```
$mainaccess -> 'userLevel'// Incorrect
$mainaccess->userLevel //correct
```

Array

```
$mainaccess -> 'userLevel'// Incorrect
$mainaccess['userLevel'] //correct
```

Please change this line

You query is also incorrect please use this block of code as your sql query is not pulling in the right info.

```
function isAdmin()
{
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "dbpass", "dbname") or die ('Could not connect to database!');  
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `usertable` WHERE userID = $_SESSION['sess_uid']";

    if($result = $mainaccess = $conn->query($sql))
    { 
        while($obj = $result->fetch_object())
        { 
            $user = $obj;
        } 
    }


    if ($user->userLevel == 0)
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I changed the SQL statement to :                                     $sql = "SELECT * FROM `usertable` WHERE userID ='" . $_SESSION['sess_uid'] . "'";

Comment: However non admin users can still access the page, i believe the problem is with my third if statement with the $mainaccess -> 'userLevel' == 0

Comment: i have remove the quotes from the object, still allowing a non administrator access to the page. the fully updated code appears at the top of the page, it has been edited

Comment: @user3296793 The way you are querying the DB is incorrect, have added another update.

Comment: I have implemented your suggested change for the query itself, however i am getting an error message on that particular line itself 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING. to get rid of that error message i formatted the query as i did before although that wasn't working either

Comment: i changed my query itself back to the way i had it and implemented your other suggested changes. it now works as intended, thanks for your assistance, it was much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You really need something like:

```
function isAdmin() {
  $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "dbpass", "dbname") or die ('Could not connect to database!');  
  $sql = "SELECT `userID` FROM `usertable` WHERE `userLevel` = 0 AND userID ='" . $_SESSION['sess_uid'] . "'";
```

As I said in the comments, you are looking for ANYONE with admin access, but you really want to know whether THIS user has admin access, therefore you have to validate what user you are trying to figure out has access. I just put the code together above, thinking you are storing the userID in the session (as per your later code) but you may need to change this

Comment: Thanks for your input, I will change my code to filter the user ids and report back with result.

Comment: With the code change implemented, any user can still access the page, i believe the error may lay within my third if statement. Would it be better to store the result from the sql in an array?

Comment: provide print_r on the query result - so we can see what data we're working with - can you SQLFiddle this?

Comment: this is the result of printing the result set of the query:mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 12 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 ) welcome administrator

Comment: updated the code at the beginning, i have changed the query gathering the result set, the object to check if the user level is "0" and the print_r statement

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong. The link should only be shown to logged in admins.

Try something like this test code.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['admin'] = 0;//set only by logging in
$html  ="Test<br>";//page html
if ($_SESSION['admin']== 0) {
      $html .="<a href=\"adminpage.php\" >Admin</a>";
}
echo $html;   
?>
```

Modify to suit your requirements.